# UITableView in UIPopoverController, didselectRowatIndexPath not getting called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have one `UITableView` in `UIPopoverController`.

Its known that when scrolling is in progress we cant not select any rows in `UITable`

When scrolling is about to end in the table, if i try to select the row, `didselectrowatindexpath` is not getting called, there after until I slightly scroll the table or tap outside the table(basically table gets loaded once again) I will not be able to select any cell in the table.

But If I give sufficient time for scrolling to end and try to select the row, `didselectrowatindexpath` is getting called.

I know its wired problem not sure how to solve this. I found similar thread in other forums and no solution was available for this.

Can some one guide me?

Comment: What you have tried in code so far?

Comment: code for presenting popover and table view data source please.